# awk - Search for multiple command line arguments in text file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

So I have a file called data.dat which contains data about some real estate separated by ';' (which district they're located in, area, price and a brief description).

For example:

```
13;78;44;garage, balcony, multiple floors  
23;100;25;garden, alarm system, unfurnished  
16;97;60;balcony, unfurnished, alarm system
```

I am writing a shell script which lists the apartments that fit the search criteria which is given in command line arguments. So for example if I run the program like this:

```
bash real.sh -search alarm system unfurnished
```

The output should be:

```
23;100;25;garden, alarm system, unfurnished  
16;97;60;balcony, unfurnished, alarm system
```

I have the following code which can check for the first word after -search:

```
if test "$1" = "-search"
   then awk -v word="$2" 'BEGIN{FS=";"} {if ($4 ~ word) {print $0}}' data.dat;
   exit 1;
fi
```

But I need this program to be able to check for any amount of words after search. How could I do that? I tried using the regex "${@:2}" instead of "$2" but that didn't work.

Comment: for the `alarm system`, you want to search the line contains `alarm[space]system` or `alarm or system` ?

Comment: The alarm[space]system one

Comment: All right, sorry, I'm kind of new here and didn't see that page.

Answer (score 0):

searching all the words regardless of order in the fourth field

```
$ awk -F';' -v words="alarm system unfurnished" '
             BEGIN {n=split(words,ks," ")} 
                   {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) if($4!~ks[i]) next}1' file

23;100;25;garden, alarm system, unfurnished  
16;97;60;balcony, unfurnished, alarm system
```

if you're looking for any of the words matched, change the last part to

```
... if($4~ks[i]) {print; next}}' file
```

not sure which one you want since the example has no partial match case.

if you want to use the user input directly change to

```
... words="${*:2}" ...
```

keeping the rest the same.  However not clear you're looking for all words to match or any one.

Comment: Thank yout for your answer! Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my description, but I need it to work with any word I input after the -search parameter, not just "alarm system unfurnished". I'll post another example for a better understanding:
Input: bash real.sh -search unfurnished balcony
Output: 16;97;60;balcony, unfurnished, alarm system

I tried your solution replacing the part after 'words=' with "${@:2}" and it works if I only input 1 word, otherwise I get an error:  "cannot open file `BEGIN{FS=";"} {n=split(words,ks," ")} {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) if($4~ks[i]) {print; next}}' for reading"

Comment: sorry, it should be `${*:2}`  Otherwise, you can do `temp="${@:2}"` and use `"$temp"` as script variable.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly now! Thank you for your patience and help! :)

Answer (score 0):

As you commented, you want exactly `foo bar` instead of `foo or bar`, then you may want to change the argument format, for example, let them be comma separated: `foo bar,blah`, this searches `foo bar` and `blah`. Otherwise you cannot distinguish `foo[space]bar` or `foo or bar`. Thus, you can do:

```
awk -F';' -v p="alarm system,unfurnished" 'BEGIN{gsub(",","|",p)} $4~p' file
```

Sure you can let the `p` variable be assigned by a shell variable:

```
awk -F';' -v p="$search" 'BEGIN{....
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you need an awk solution?

```
$ cat patterns
alarm
system
furnished

$ egrep -f patterns file
23;100;25;garden, alarm system, unfurnished  
16;97;60;balcony, unfurnished, alarm system
```